# Email Reply To PHP script process

Tags: php, perl, email, imap

I'm making a Purchase Order system.  All of our POs go out to our vendors via gmail SMTP server in PHP. I'm using Perl Mail for that.

Currently the reply-to is set to the from email, which is of course the gmail address.  My goal, is to let vendors Reply To that PO email, and me grab that data and put it into my database.

I tried grabbing the IMAP Inbox via PHP and looking for the messages. But encrypted messages are unreadable, and I feel like it's hacky.

Is there a way, to make the reply-to email go back to my server, instead of gmail. And then have some light mail server running on my server to catch all email, or email with something in the from address (or subject) and then process the contents?

Thanks!

Comment: encrypted emails? are you speaking of base64 encoded?

Comment: Use the mx records of your server instead of google.

Comment: you can pipe email to a script, then process that, we do it for bounces, the pipe command depends on your mail server. the alternative is to use imap to access the emails

Comment: Looks like the encoding was because I was fetching part 2 instead of part 1 in IMAP.

Comment: If I change the MX records all mail will go to my server.  I just want the reply-to to hit my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dragon for pointing me in the right direction.

Add this to your /etc/aliases file (if you have postfix installed)

```
process | "/path/to/php/script.php"
```

Then run

```
newaliases
```

Then run

```
/etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

The PHP script looks like this

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test SET thing = '$data'");
```